# Can non-brake silicone lube be a good substitute for hydraulic seal lubricants in brakes?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, lubricant

[Hope suggest using Hunter silicone lubricant (SC960)](https://youtu.be/v83YFGi5uT0) when assembling pistons, etc, on their (DOT 5.1) hydraulic brakes. It is supposed to be easily available but it took me a while to find some at a sensible price.

I noticed that [überlube](https://www.uberlube.com/) advertise that their silicone lubricant can be used for other purposes (such as defrizzing hair and for anti-chafing in sports). This made me wonder: Would that kind of silicone lube (ie. überlube, Pjur, Astroglide, etc) be safe to use around these other hydraulics?

---

As an aside, red rubber grease is often recommended and I certainly see some advertised as DOT safe. The ones I've found look to be around [NLGI 2](https://www.hambini.com/grease-for-bicycles-a-practical-guide/) consistency. From the Hope video, the Hunter lube looks to be like NLGI 0 or 00. Should I be able to find red rubber grease in a similar consistency?

Comment: I flagged this as spam, but now I am not sure is. Why would you, the correct fluid is cheap and easy to get.

Comment: @mattnz Simple curiosity. If one can [replace hydraulic fluid with baby oil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63VIuPiX3CA), maybe one kind of silicone lube is just as good as another?

Comment: Use the recommended stuff on brakes for safety's sake. Other lube may be OK for a squeaking saddle.

Comment: @mattnz yeah the title was a bit distracting, so I edited it down.  The underlying question seems fair, though to be honest the prime users of those lubricants might be put off reading it as "okay for disk brakes"

Comment: This confuses me - DOT5 brake fluid is silicon-based but DOT5.1 brake fluid is mineral oil based, and they are not interchangeable.  I'd have *guessed* that silicon and mineral should not be mixed, but its not my area.  The MSDS https://www.theultimatefinish.co.uk/documents/MSDS/Angelwax-Uber-Lube.pdf and https://www.hunterplastics.co.uk/media/1843/data-sheet-silicone-spray-sc967.pdf suggest significant differences but both have 25% and 10-30% propane respectively.  Comment because guess, not answer.

Comment: @Criggie My girlfriend didn't think much of the idea of using it for her hair either... Note that SC967 is a spray so maybe has different composition to SC960. And for more confusion, it's not obvious that the UK [Angelwax](http://www.angelwax.co.uk)'s "clay bar lubricant" whose COSSH sheet you linked is the same as the lube from the US company I linked in my question.

Comment: wikipedia tells me that [dimethicone/polydimethylsiloxane/PDMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydimethylsiloxane) is common to both intimate and industrial lubes.

Comment: I guess there are more than one component in the silicon grease, and I'd think it would be best to use a grease where all components are guaranteed to be compatible with the DOT 5.1 fluid and the rubber bushings in the caliper?

Comment: @MagnusK I haven't checked the others, but uberlube has only [4 ingredients](https://www.uberlube.com/ask-uberlube/2019/10/3/what-are-the-ingredients): dimethicone, dimethiconol & cyclomethicone + vitamin E. I was under the impression a grease was basically a lubricant with stuff added to make it semi-solid. Note from the Hope video that the recommended Hunter SC960 lubricant seems less viscous than a typical grease (it comes in a pouring bottle).

Comment: @MagnusK Apparently [Hayes says](https://www.mtbr.com/threads/dot-grease-for-sticky-pistons.1109435/#post-14220025): we can't recommend "silicone grease" in general because there could be one with additives that harm the seal

Comment: @jhnc Based on what Hayes (sorry but I don't recognise that name?) says, then I'd use only what the brake manufacturer specifies. Brakes that don't work correctly is a safety hazard?

Comment: Too many brake manufactures and other names, I got lost with Hayes. =)

Comment: @MagnusK I had not heard of them either but I assume from the context that it is [this Hayes](https://hayesbicycle.com/collections/brakes).